# Mapping LUIS Utterance with Intent

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Framework: **Microsoft Bot Framework**

I have a requirement in LUIS to get the entity details based on an intent.

Intent name: **SingleWord**
Entity name: **Book**
Attributes: **Version, Book, Chapter, Word** 
Example Utterance: **2 turningpoints 3:1**

Here 
2 - **Version** 
turningpoints - **Book**
3 - **Chapter**
1 - **Word**

I am unable to map the below Utterance with the SingleWord intent as we do not have space in between
**2turningpoints3:1**

I have also tried with Phrase lists option as well but no luck.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The [Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-tutorial-pattern) feature with the Patterns.any entity should fix this.